# Invert all colors from within the application

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Is it possible to replicate the white on black feature that the iphone has from within an application.

I am trying to set up a toggle and when turned on the application will invert all of it's colors. Essentially creating a 'night time mode'

Comment: night-time means 'dark'. Inverting the colors just turns it into a negative, which can easily be as bright (or brighter) than the original view.

Comment: My interface is originally bright. So when I turn it to white on black it becomes 'dark'.

Comment: @endy So i dont get how to use CIColorInvert on UIViews whith dynamic content. Do you have an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Core Image. There is a filter called `CIColorInvert` which inverts the colors in an image. You can find out more about Core Image filters [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html).

If you want some help with Core Image, you could check out this tutorial by Ray Wenderlich: [Beginning Core Image in iOS 5 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5689/beginning-core-image-in-ios-5)

Hope this helps!